# ValidateInputAttribute not working in Post Request of ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, validation, xss, sql-injection

My understanding was OOTB, MVC will validate input to prevent XSS Attack and SQL Injection.

For example, In one of my app, the "a dangerous input has been detected" error will be received when I put   in HTTP Get request. However, the post actions can let these values posted successfully through html input element without error. Even after I marked the controller action as [ValidateInput(true)]. How can I make them validate those post input?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your GET handler, or what you're sending to it, it's tough to say why it behaves that way.  However, OOTB MVC guards against SQL injection through the use of Entity Framework, and against XSS through ModelState validation.

Inside the body of your POST action that handles this forms submission you'll want to use code much like the following:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //do the stuff I want to do when things are valid and free of XSS
}
else
{
    //something went wrong.  Probably shouldn't process this one.  Have the user try again
}
```

Update: please disregard my filthy lies.  ValidateInput(true) is not necessary because it is on by default.  So, the only things I can think of would be that you have the AllowHtml attribute on your class or properties, or you are not posting back a model for modelBinding, and therefore input validation, to occur.  At this point, you're probably going to need to put up some code for further help.  There's too many unknowns right now.

Comment: I cannot agree more. There were no such attributes on those things mate. I will have a investigate further when I have time, and let you know later.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue - we had JQuery using `$.ajax` to post JSON to the MVC action. The default model binder does not validate posted JSON allowing unsafe XSS to be posted against our action.

To solve this, I found the `RequestValidator` has a static method `InvokeIsValidRequestString` that allowed

```
public class ValidateJsonXssAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext?.Request;
        if (request != null && "application/json".Equals(request.ContentType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (request.ContentLength > 0 && request.Form.Count == 0) // 
            {
                if (request.InputStream.Position > 0)
                    request.InputStream.Position = 0; // InputStream has already been read once from "ProcessRequest"
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
                {
                    var postedContent = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Get posted JSON content
                    var isValid = RequestValidator.Current.InvokeIsValidRequestString(HttpContext.Current, postedContent,
                        RequestValidationSource.Form, "postedJson", out var failureIndex); // Invoke XSS validation
                    if (!isValid) // Not valid, so throw request validation exception
                        throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Potentially unsafe input detected");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can just decorate relevant MVC actions expecting JSON-posted data that might bypass the standard XSS prevention:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateJsonXss]
public ActionResult PublishRecord(RecordViewModel vm) { ... }
```

You can see other options for customizing request validation with OWASP .NET recommendations by extending the RequestValidator object, which exposes the string validation done by the `ValidateInput` automatically utilized by MVC for other scenarios of query string, form collection, and cookie values.

For more info: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation